# Converting XML file into a specific JSON format

Tags: json, xml, powershell

I have an XML file that looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="application" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Parameter1" Value="test1" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter2" Value="test2" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter3" Value="test3" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter4" Value="test4" />
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```

I am using a hashtable to convert this to JSON but when I do, I only get the Parameters portion:

```json
{
    "PARAMETER_1":  "Test",
    "parameter2" :  "test2"
```

I'm Reading the xml file like so because if i try to read it as $appParametersXml then I get an error.

```
$appParametersHashTable = Read-XmlElementAsHashtable $appParametersXml.Application.Parameters

$appParametersHashTable |ConvertTo-Json |Out-File "C:\Workspaces\ARMTemplates\GhostDraftApplication\ARMTemplate\CloudAXF.json"
#$appParametersHashTable|ConvertFrom-Xml|Out-File "C:\Workspaces\ARMTemplates\GhostDraftApplication\ARMTemplate\CloudTest.xml"

$appParametersXml | ConvertFrom-Xml | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 | Out-File "C:\Workspaces\ARMTemplates\GhostDraftApplication\ARMTemplate\CloudAXF.json"

$xmlObject = $appParametersXml | ConvertTo-Xml


###############################################################################
function Read-XmlElementAsHashtable
{
    Param (
        [System.Xml.XmlElement]
        $Element
    )

    $hashtable = @{}
    if ($Element.ChildNodes)
    {
        $Element.ChildNodes | 
            ForEach-Object {
                    $hashtable["Name" + $_.Name] = "Value" + $_.Value
            }
    }

    return $hashtable
}
```

Is there a way to read the all the tags and attributes from the xml file and convert them to JSON so it looks like this?

```
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "PARAMETER_1": {
        "value": "Test"
    },
```

I've just been spinning my wheels.

Comment: Sorry, my xml file didn't post correctly: It looks like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="Test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="PARAMTER_1" Value="Test" />

Comment: I fixed the code fences for you (it's three backticks, not three single-quotes), can you [update the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64463941/edit) with a complete and valid XML document please?

Comment: Thankyou! i've updated the post with the xml document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can hard-code what attributes to extract from the `Parameter` XML elements, you can do the following:

```bsh
# Sample XML input.
[xml] $xmlDoc = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="application" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Parameter1" Value="test1" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter2" Value="test2" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter3" Value="test3" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter4" Value="test4" />
  </Parameters>
</Application>
'@ 
  
# Transform the "Parameter" elements into a nested hashtable.
$hash = [ordered] @{}
$xmlDoc.Application.Parameters.ChildNodes | % {
  $hash[$_.Name] = @{ value = $_.Value }
}

# Wrap the hashtable in a top-level hashtable and convert to JSON.
[ordered] @{
  '$schema' = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#'
  contentVersion ='1.0.0.0'
  parameters = $hash
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

The above yields:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "Parameter1": {
      "value": "test1"
    },
    "parameter2": {
      "value": "test2"
    },
    "parameter3": {
      "value": "test3"
    },
    "parameter4": {
      "value": "test4"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: If you additionally want to perform *type conversions* on the XML input before converting to JSON, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64485496/45375) to a closely related question.

Comment: I've added a link to your other question to the answer, in case people get here first while also looking for type conversions.