# How to convert integer xml value to JSON without quotes

Tags: json, xml, powershell

So, I have my xml like shown below with Parameter 4 being an integer and the rest being string parameters. The problem is that XML doesn't allow me to put the integer value without quotes (it doesn't like that).

When I convert it to JSON, I want the integer value to come over without the quotes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="application" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Parameter1" Value="test1" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter2" Value="test2" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter3" Value="test3" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter4" Value="42" />
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```

I have a nested hash table (Thanks @mklement0 for assisting me with that)

```
    $hash = [ordered] @{}
    $appParametersXml.Application.Parameters.ChildNodes | % {
    $hash[$_.Name] = @{ value = $_.Value }
    }

    # Wrap the hashtable in a top-level hashtable and convert to JSON.
    [ordered] @{
    '$schema' = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#'
    contentVersion ='1.0.0.0'
    parameters = $hash
   } | ConvertTo-Json |Out-File $parameterJsonFile
```

The output in the JSON file is correct, however, the last value (`42`) is also coming over within quotes. Is there a way to specify that one specific value is an integer?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: The [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-common-syn) is pretty clear about this: Only string literals and references can be used as attribute values, and they must be delimited using single- or double-quotes. If you want to convert it to JSON as an integer value, you'll have to explicitly convert it to one _before_ calling `ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML is *text*-based**, so any values you extract from an `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) document will be *strings*.

<sup>To quote from [Mathias R. Jessen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) comment on the question:
"The [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-common-syn) is pretty clear about this: Only string literals and references can be used as attribute values, and they must be delimited using single- or double-quotes."</sup>

If you want those values to be **other types**, you must **perform *explicit conversions***.

Passing such converted values to `ConvertTo-Json` will then automatically omit the quotes if they are of a type that is represented unquoted in JSON (numbers, `null`, `true` and `false`)

In the case at hand, you can use `-as`, the [conditional type conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators), to conditionally convert a string to an integer, *if* it can be interpreted as such:

```bsh
# Sample XML input.
# Note the two "Value" attribute values, "test1" and "42".
[xml] $xmlDoc = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="application" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Parameter1" Value="test1" />
    <Parameter Name="parameter4" Value="42" />
  </Parameters>
</Application>
'@ 
  
# Transform the "Parameter" elements into a nested hashtable.
# Convert any values that can be interpreted as [int] to [int].
$hash = [ordered] @{}
$xmlDoc.Application.Parameters.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object {
  $hash[$_.Name] = @{
    # Convert the text value to an [int], if it can be parsed as such.
    value = if ($num = $_.Value -as [int]) { $num } else { $_.Value }
  }
}

# Wrap the hashtable in a top-level hashtable and convert to JSON.
[ordered] @{
  '$schema' = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#'
  contentVersion ='1.0.0.0'
  parameters = $hash
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

The above yields the following: note how `42` is *unquoted*:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "Parameter1": {
      "value": "test1"
    },
    "parameter4": {
      "value": 42
    }
  }
}
```